# How to: Bandwidth Calculator in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, bandwidth, calculator

I am wondering is there any silver sample project available which can monitor the local network traffic (bytes sent received) precisely IPv4InterfaceStatistics like information.

---

Jeff thanks.

I found some tips from this link: http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures

Comment: According to the link, it's only available out of browser, is that what you want, or do you want it available in a browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available to a typical Silverlight 4 application.

It may be possible to use an elevated out-of-browser Silverlight app and the COM automation/interop features to query WMI or other systme information services, but it will be a lot more work than using a tool that is designed to have rights to the system instead (such as WPF or Win32).